# Call URL when order status change

Tags: api, callback

Is it possible to develop an extension that calls an external URL with some information about an order, let's say when an order is `fulfilled/sent`. Its because we want to integrate with another system, that sends out customer review request emails.

So we want to "ping" their system when order status changes, and then in the other system we can then choose the sending delays, so that the other system sends the review request 4-5 days after order is sent.

Comment: Please specify your magento version.

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sales_order_save_after` it's triggered right after an order is saved in the database and returns the full order object.

So when ever an order status is changed you can call the api and send your order data.